# Is it possible to trigger different task for different changed files in bitbucket pipeline?

Tags: configuration, continuous-integration, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

For example.

My repo contains a three folders: "project1" "project2" and "core".

When I change a files under "core" folder I want trigger "npm run test Project1" and "npm run test project2".

If I changed the "project1" files I want test only "project 1".
If I changed the "poject2" - I want test only "project2".

I don't want to separate this folders on separate repositories, or use git submodules and subthrees. And also I don't want to every time test everything.

I heard that in teamcity such task is called triggers.

Does the "bitbucket pipeline" support this a kind of feature?

Answer (score 2):

Bitbucket pipelines offers [conditional steps](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/configure-bitbucket-pipelinesyml/#condition) ([as of 2020](https://bitbucket.org/blog/conditional-steps-and-improvements-to-logs-in-bitbucket-pipelines)).

This entirely skips running the step if the includePaths requirement is not met. It accepts a list of file path globs, so you can have it only run for certain file, or group of files.

```yaml
- step:
    name: project1 tests
    # Run if project1 config or src changes, but not README
    condition:
      changesets:
        includePaths:
          - project1/config/**
          - project1/src/**
    script:
      - echo "Test project1"

- step:
    name: project2 tests
    # Run if any file in project 2 changes
    condition:
      changesets:
        includePaths:
          - project2/**
    script:
      - echo "Test project2"

- step:
    name: migration file validation
    # Run if any of the python migration scripts have changed
    condition:
      changesets:
        includePaths:
          - **/migrations/*.py
    script:
      - echo "Test migration compatibility"
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this using a custom bash script like this:

```
for DIFF in `git diff --name-only HEAD^1 HEAD`
do
    FOLDER=`echo $DIFF | awk -F/ '{print $1}'`
    if [ $FOLDER = functions ]
    then

    fi
done
```

The first line gives you a list with the paths of the files that were changed in the last commit, the third line is like a javascript split, with which i separate the path on the "/" character and get the first part of it (This way i'm just getting the outer folder of the diff) finally i evaluate the folder name and do something accordingly, here you put all the conditions you need

Answer (score 0):

Grep output from `git diff` and executes your deploy script from within the directory.

Let's assume the following folder structure:

```
├─ src
│  └─ project1
│     └─ deploy.sh
│  └─ project2
│     └─ deploy.sh
```

```yaml
- step:
    name: Build and packages if changed
    script:
      - echo "Building and packaging projects"
      - git diff --name-only HEAD HEAD~1 | grep "src/project1" && (cd src/project1 && ./deploy.sh)
      - git diff --name-only HEAD HEAD~1 | grep "src/project2" && (cd src/project2 && ./deploy.sh)
```